# App Update Won't Install

Tags: android, apk, updates, keystore, jarsigner

com.blastmnt.alarmclock

Old APK

- versionCode="4"
- versionName="0.2.3.0"

New APK

- versionCode="5"
- versionName="0.2.3.1"

I have created a keystore in the terminal using keytool:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore alarm.keystore -alias alarmalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And exported a signed project through the ADT Bundle, pointed it to the keystore file.

Users/Me/Documents/Android/workspace/alarmclock [project directory]

Users/Me/Documents/Android/keystore/alarm.keystore

---

After that not working after multiple attempts, saying that the signature wasn't the same I tried jarsigner, and exported an unsigned project instead.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore alarmclock.keystore alarmclock.apk clockalias
```

Then verified them with:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs alarmclock.apk
```

Uploaded the newer one to a URL on my server, deleted it from my computer, then repeated the process, with changing the version code and name down, and uploaded it to my devices, then went to try to download the newer files.

The Moto X just says "App not installed", and in the LogCat it says:

> Installation Error Code -25

While the RAZR M says that the signatures aren't the same.

Tried it again, making sure that I didn't magically swap version files, and then repeated the whole process to make sure I did the key right, and compared the jarsigner verify outputs to make sure everything was in line, same problem.

Please help, I am really at a loss at this point.  I am probably just doing something stupid wrong, but for the life of me I don't see it.  Thank you so much for any help at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a wise man once said, if you can't find a solution, it is because you're asking the wrong question.

The server wasn't dumping the old file, when a new one was uploaded to override it.  So both phones were correct, wrong signature and version error (-25).

Figured that out by emailing myself the new file to update, realized it worked, then broke everything down from there when I realized the APK wasn't the problem.

Thank you everyone who has viewed the question to try to help.  I am absolutely grateful for your time.